# Running into issues installing ruby 2.0 with rvm

Tags: rvm

The error I keep getting when rvm is trying to import the default gemsets, is:

```
    ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time...............................
    /Users/****/.rvm/scripts/functions/support: line 291: 84474 Segmentation fault: 11  "$ruby_path" -rrbconfig -e '\
        File.open("'"$config_path"'","w") { |file|
          RbConfig::CONFIG.sort.each{|key,value|
            file.write("#{key.gsub(/\.|-/,"_")}=\"#{value.gsub("$","\\$")}\"\n")
          }
        }

  ' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

rvm -v

rvm 1.21.17 () by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

xcode 4.6.3

`uname -a`
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

sw_vers -productVersion :10.7.5

Comment: what version of OSX is it `sw_vers -productVersion` and `uname -a` - add it to the question.

Comment: Updated the details requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be happening because this ruby was build on OSX 10.8 and this is OSX 10.7 (like mentioned in the other answer), you can make sure it's all fine with disabling binary rubies:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --disable-binary
```

this will tell rvm to not search for binary and to go straight to compile process.

If this works for you then [open a ticket for rvm](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/new) to prepare binaries which are compatible with OSX 10.7

### Update 2013.08.06

I have removed the link to binary `osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247` - if you prefer to use binaries then please [open a ticket for rvm](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/new) to build version for your system.

Comment: It couldn't find binaries for 10.7 x86_64 and did build it from source. I think that steps works ok. When its trying to install the default gemset is when the segfault occurs.

Comment: Tried the above and its definitely trying to get the source but its hanging trying to do that:  

`No archive, downloading
Running(11): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --create-dirs -C - -o ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2 http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2`  

`nslookup http://ftp.ruby-lang.org
Server:  75.75.75.75
Address: 75.75.75.75#53

** server can't find http://ftp.ruby-lang.org: NXDOMAIN.
`
LOcation of source changed?

Comment: make sure your network is configured correctly, the ruby server is hosted at address: 221.186.184.68

Answer (score 0):

If the code you are showing segfaults, it must be a bug in Ruby 2.0. I recommend that you submit a bug report to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem at OS X 10.7.5

I tried: **sudo rvm reinstall 2.0.0**, but it fails again.

Finally I chose to install a previous version with:

**sudo rvm install 1.9.3** and all its ok

Comment: Yes, 1.9.3 worked fine for me also. Its 2.0 which always keeps running into this. I have even tried imploding rvm and starting from scratch.

Comment: never ever use `sudo`, i you have to (and you don't in this case) use `rvmsudo`